# How to set path to jar file in Dockerfile?

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm trying to run Spring application by **docker compose up** and then I have error

> ERROR [2/2] COPY target/*.jar app.jar

My thoughts are that the path is wrong in Dockerfile to jar file.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  app-backend:
    image: my-app
    ports:
      - "8010:8080"
  build:
    context: .
    dockerfile: "Dockerfile"
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:11-jdk
EXPOSE 8010
ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} my-app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-Dspring.profiles.active=dev", "-jar", "/my-app.jar"]
```

And here is a structure of my project

[image: structure]

So my question is: what is wrong with this path or what causes this error?

Comment: You're running `docker build` out of the `src/main/Docker/dev` directory, but your actual source files are several directories above this.  Move the `docker-compose.yml` and `Dockerfile` up to the top level of your repository, next to the `pom.xml` file.

Comment: when you have the source as many `*.jar` and target as single `app.jar` , it is not right!

Comment: @DavidMaze but is it possible to refer to a jar file using ../../ in Dockerfile ARG?

Comment: No, you can never `COPY` from a higher-level directory than the Dockerfile (or more correctly the `build:` or `build: { context: }` directory).

Comment: Piotror: a dockerfile cannot reference files in a higher-level directory. This is because `docker build` doesn't actually do the building itself -- it packages up the identified directory and everything _below_ it (but not above) and sends them as 'context' to the _daemon_ which does the build -- using _only_ the 'context'. You could exclude the `src` tree that isn't needed using [`.dockerignore`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#dockerignore-file)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can try using the Makefile to automate some work for you?

here is a sample implementation:

```
POM_VERSION = $(shell mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version -q -DforceStdout)

build:
    cp target/app-$(POM_VERSION).jar src/main/Docker/dev/my-app.jar

docker-build: build
    cd src/main/Docker/dev && docker-compose up
```

place this Makefile in root dir.

and Dockerfile should be:

```
FROM openjdk:11-jdk
EXPOSE 8010
ADD my-app.jar my-app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-Dspring.profiles.active=dev", "-jar", "/my-app.jar"]
```

now simply run: `make docker-build`

make sure that the makefile has tabular spaces